# Find items in one of list of lists in a second list of lists

Tags: python-2.7

I have 2 lists both containing lists. I want the the first two items in each list in `missing_cards` used as search criteria in `master_memory`. If it finds them in `master_memory`, it should print the list it found in `master_memory`. If it cannot find it in `master_memory`, it prints "Not in the Master list:" and then the first 2 items of that list in `missing_cards`.

I want it to print:

Not available, location is: a b tagged

Not available, location is: a b favorites

Not in the Master list: c d

Not in the Master list: e f

I have tried:

```
card_name = 0
card_set = 1
card_location = 2
missing_cards=[['a','b','1'],['c','d','1'],['e','f','1']]
master_memory=[['a','b','tagged'],['c','e','slot_1'],['a','b','favorites'],['f','p','slot_2']


for missing_cards_row in missing_cards:
    if (missing_cards_row[card_name],missing_cards_row[card_set]) not in master_memory:
        print "Not in the Master list:",missing_cards_row[card_name],missing_cards_row[card_set]
    else:
        for master_memory_row in master_memory:
            if missing_cards_row[card_name]==master_memory_row[card_name] and missing_cards_row[card_set]==master_memory_row[card_set]:
                print "Not available, location is:",master_memory_row[card_name], master_memory_row[card_set], master_memory_row[card_location]
```

but this doesn't work. It says all items in `missing_cards` are not in `master_memory` because it doesn't find exactly that list in 'master_memory', even though I want it to just look at the first two items in each list. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use nested for loops.

```
card_name = 0
card_set = 1
card_location = 2
for missing_cards_row in missing_cards:
    #This variable will keep track, if the card is found or not
    found = false; 
    for master_memory_row in master_memory:
        if(missing_cards_row[card_name]==master_memory_row[card_name] and missing_cards_row[card_set]==master_memory_row[card_set]):
             print "Not available, location is:",master_memory_row[card_name], master_memory_row[card_set], master_memory_row[card_location]
             found = true
    #This flag will inform if the missing card is found in master card or not
    if (found==false): 
        print "Not in the Master list:",missing_cards_row[card_name],missing_cards_row[card_set]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the following:

```
card_name = 0
card_set = 1
card_location = 2
missing_cards=[['a','b','1'],['c','d','1'],['e','f','1']]
master_memory=[['a','b','tagged'],['c','e','slot_1'],['a','b','favorites'],['f','p','slot_2']]

# Assuming missing_cards always has triplets, loop and extract each value
for x,y,z in missing_cards:

    # Remember if we had at least one match in master_memory
    found = False

    # Loop master_memory and check for existance of x y in it
    for mm in master_memory:

        # Check the first 2 elements
        if x in mm and y in mm:
            # Print matching location
            print "Not available, location is: %s" % ' '.join(mm)
            # Flag as found in master_memory
            found = True

    # Once here, check if that we had at least one match - if not print relevant message
    if not found:
        print "Not in the Master list: %s %s" % (x, y)
```

Output:

```
Not available, location is: a b tagged
Not available, location is: a b favorites
Not in the Master list: c d
Not in the Master list: e f
```

The above makes few assumptions:

1. `missing_cards` is always triplets:

   This can me changed to `for mc in missing_cards` and later be used as `mc[0]` and `mc[1]` for checks, instead of `x` and `y`. That way the number of items in `missing_cards` can vary
2. Matching order does not matter, ie (a, b) will match (b, a):

   If this needs to change, instead of `x in mm` one should use `x == mm[0] and y == mm[1]`. This way we also ensure that the missing_cards items appear in the same order in `master_memory`

Comment: @asajunk Any feedback or concerns regarding the above assumptions? If you update the question I can adjust the answer if needed

Comment: This is really great too! Thank you for your help. Yes, I think missing_cards will always be triplets. Matching order probably doesn't matter, although in a rare case perhaps it could.